# Convenient way to run eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have recently started developing an Eclipse plugin (which is basic stuff for now) and I am struggling with "default" way to run Eclipse plugin ("Run as Eclipse application").

The Eclipse is starting another instance with my plugin already installed in it (this is default behaviour).

The problem is that when I want to re-run my plugin project and I press "run" button again (or Ctrl + F11) (and the another Eclipse instance still running) I get following message:

"Could not launch the application because the associated workspace is currently in use by another Eclipse application".

The error makes sense, and when I close "testing" Eclipse instance I am able to run my plugin again.

The question is - "is it normal routine for plugin development?". Maybe I am missing something, e.g. special arguments for Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems all pretty normal. The error message is since the run configuration is specifing a workspace and when you start a second instance using the same workspace it is locked and considered in use.

What I usually do when testing a plugin is to create a run configuration (click "Run...") where I disable all the plugins I wont need when testing. This makes sure that the test starts up a couple of seconds quicker. Make sure you save that run configuration as a *.launch file aswell, that makes it quicker to test the next time. Or it can be used to share the configuration.

There's a lot you can configure in the run configuration, such as eclipse arguments, vm argument, if you want environment variables set, etc. So be sure to experiment a little.

Answer (score 2):

In your run configuration. Main tab->Workspace Data ->Location text box add this:

`${workspace_loc}/../runtime-EclipseApplication${current_date:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}`

Note the suffix **${current_date:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}** by this every time you launch your application new workspace will be created. So you will not get any error message saying workspace is locked.

But be careful as the folder **.metadata** will be different for different instances as their work-spaces are different. Thus preferences stored/retrieved by different instances are NOT in sync.

Comment: that is not really convinient for me, because in that case I will have to recreate project that I use to test my plugin on

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing one important point: Eclipse supports the [Java hot code replacement](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F). Therefore in many cases you can modify your Java code while your application Eclipse instance is running, save the code and **continue without restarting**.

If hot code replacement is not possible, Eclipse will tell you, so you always know whether the editing changes are applied to the running instance.

This works best with more recent versions of the JVM, so consider upgrading to the latest Java 7 version, even if you write code to be compliant with Java 1.5 or 6.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of hot replacement. Actually I have decided to develop my plugin "processing" code separately (like ordinary java application) and then merge it with plugin UI.